# loading clips construct with clipspy

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, clips, clipspy

Just installed [clipspy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clipspy) on a windows-10 64bit; and testing in a Jupyter notebook 
I have;

```
from clips import Environment, Symbol 
import os 
env = Environment
env.load('D:\\Documents\\Clips\\clipspy\\Tree_Solve_Learn.clp')
```

And get this

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-a08421f4802a> in <module>()
----> 1 env.load('D:\\Documents\\Clips\\clipspy\\Tree_Solve_Learn.clp')

TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'
```

So got an ls

```
 Volume in drive D is DATA
 Volume Serial Number is 443F-982E

 Directory of D:\Documents\Clips\clipspy

12/04/2017  07:52 PM    <DIR>          .

12/04/2017  07:52 PM    <DIR>          ..

12/04/2017  07:44 PM    <DIR>          .ipynb_checkpoints

12/03/2017  07:03 PM                59 1stText.py

12/03/2017  01:32 PM               925 animal.dat

10/17/2017  06:43 PM    <DIR>          clipspy

10/17/2017  06:53 PM            20,766 clipspy-0.1.0.tar.gz

12/03/2017  01:30 PM             3,373 Tree_Solve_Learn.clp

12/03/2017  09:19 PM            19,311 Untitled.ipynb

12/03/2017  09:22 PM               555 Untitled1.ipynb

12/03/2017  09:19 PM                72 Untitled2.ipynb

12/04/2017  07:52 PM             1,972 Untitled3.ipynb

               8 File(s)         47,033 bytes

               4 Dir(s)  1,862,987,104,256 bytes free
```

and the *.clp* file is there

struggling `w/` the documentation - mostly cause I am not that experienced but not a total beginner

Anybody else trying **'clipspy'** in a Window's environment?

Thanks 
WJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example it seems you are not initializing the `Environment` object correctly.

```
from clips import Environment, Symbol 
import os 
env = Environment()  # <--- initialize the object like this
env.load('D:\\Documents\\Clips\\clipspy\\Tree_Solve_Learn.clp')
```

Comment: Thanks was too easy -

Comment: Please mark the question as "resolved" if so. This helps people to understand if a question is still pending or not.